# Combining two columns as a nested list of tuples by category | python dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Assume I have a dataframe: `df = pd.DataFrame({"cat":['a', 'a', 'b', 'c'],"A":[5, 6, 1, 4],"B":[7,8, 12, 5]})`
which looks like this:

```
   cat  A   B
0   a   5   7
1   a   6   8
2   b   1   12
3   c   4   5
```

Now I want to combine column *A* and *B* based on column *cat*. If `row['cat']` is the same, then combine `row['A']` and `row['B']` to list of tuples. So the above example's desired output is: `[[(5, 7), (6, 8)], [(1, 12)], [(4, 5)]]`

Anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
x = df.groupby('cat').apply(lambda x: list(zip(x['A'], x['B'])))
```

This gives you a series of this form:

```
cat
a    [(5, 7), (6, 8)]
b           [(1, 12)]
c            [(4, 5)]
dtype: object
```

You can do `x.to_list()` to get a list like in example output.

Answer (score 0):

You can first aggregate as tuples, then to list:

```
(df[['A', 'B']].agg(tuple, axis=1)
 .groupby(df['cat']).agg(list)
 #.to_list() # uncomment for a list
 )
```

Output:

```
cat
a    [(5, 7), (6, 8)]
b           [(1, 12)]
c            [(4, 5)]
dtype: object
```